# safari browser keydown event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am trying to catch command+r (safari). Below code works for chrome,IE,Firefox

```html
$(document.body).on("keydown", this, function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 82) {
        alert('ctrl+r event fired.')
    }
    if (event.metaKey && event.keyCode == 82) {
        alert('command+r event fired.')
    }
});
```

Need help with catching this event on safari browser.

I want to show custom message to user on when user clicks command+r on safari browser.

Answer (score 1):

As `cmd-R` forces a page reload on **Safari** you cannor catch this key combination.

**Before the event is captured** the JavaScript execution is halted and the page reloaded.

For this reason you cannnot even override the browser default behavior with `evt.preventDefault();` as this code never gets executed.

---

As `cmd-R` is universally "reload the page" for Safari users then it would be bad user experience to override that behaviour with a different one (even if it would be possibile).

I think avoiding `cmd-R` to be overridden by JavaScript code is intentional by Safari developers. What if you override `cmd-R` (reload), `cmd-Q` (quit), `cmd-W` (close window). From a UX perspective you would "break" the appication.